# Unity VRTK4 Snap Zone, how do you set the initial or default object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

I'm trying to use the Tilia snapzone utility from VRTK 4 and I can't figure out how to set the initial game object.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to this question at the discussions page for the Tilia Snap Zone

https://github.com/ExtendRealityLtd/Tilia.Interactions.SnapZone.Unity/discussions/98